# Access data from Google sheets in DialogFlow's index.JS

Tags: dialogflow-es, google-sheets-api

I am very new to DialogFlow.
I need to access data from one of my google sheet . 
How can I achieve this by coding in inbuilt Index.JS provided by DialogFlow

Comment: This is a very broad question. Showing us what you've tried and what you're having problems with is a better way to get a useful answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

In your index.js, you'll need to setup Intent handlers for each Intent.

In those handlers, you can get the parameters from the Intent and then make calls to the [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/) to get data based on those parameters.